# Rails Request Rspec Jbuilder, request.body is a StringIO object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on a project in Ruby on Rails, and I decided to use Jbuilder for handling the json serialization of my models. However when using Rspec to test my controllers with request specs, using the `*.json.jbuilder` views, my `request.body` comes back as a `StringIO` object, not a `String`.

My method in the affected controller looks like:

```
def list
  @groups = ...
end
```

And the `list.json.jbuilder` file looks like:

```
json.array! @groups, :id, :name
```

The test snippet looks like:

```
get '/api/v1/groups', { :format => :json }
puts request.body.class.name # gives StringIO instead of String...
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.2, Ruby 2.2.2, Rspec-Rails 3.3.2 and JBuilder 2.3.0

I have set in my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.render_views # tried with config.render_views = true too
```

The stacktrace for the exception is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(json['groups'].length).to eq (2)
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of StringIO into String
```

I can add that it *works* when not using Rspec.

Thanks

Comment: Don't set `config.render_views` in your  in your rails_helper.rb since it will slow down all your controller specs. Do it on a per spec basis or in a context block instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the output of your controller you need to use `response.body` not `request.body`. `request.body`is what is sent by the client when submitting a form.

Comment: I have no idea why Rack::Test (which RSpec controller test are built on top of) uses a StringIO object for the `request.body` but that's another question.

Comment: 2 hours of googling and this was the error -.-, this is what happens when you code for too long without taking breaks...